# How to use form-check-inline with fieldset and legend

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a form like this image.

[image]

And I wrote this code. It seems working, but this code break the rule that `legend` tag must be direct child of `form-group`.

```
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Checkbox</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">2</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

To solve the problem I set the `row` class to `fieldset`.

```
<fieldset class="form-group row">
  <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2">Checkbox</legend>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

Or change the order of the tags.

```
<div class="row">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
  ...
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

But both didn't work.

How can I create a form like the image while keeping the `legend` tag as direct child of `fieldset`?